# backuppc method tar no files dumped for share

Tags: linux, backup, tar

1. Ubuntu 11.10 Server; backuppc 3.2.1
2. Running cgi-bin version
3. Installed as user www-data to avoid issues with perl and apache2 with user backuppc
4. ssh works fine to servers on LAN being backed up
5. The following commandline is reported in the failure log:

   /usr/bin/ssh -q -x -n -l root 192.168.1.70 env LC_ALL=C /bin/tar -c -v -f - -C / --totals .

The log indicates:
  full backup started for directory /
  Xfer PIDs are now 26168,26167
  Tar exited with error 65280 () status
  tarExtract: Done: 0 errors, 0 filesExist, 0 sizeExist, 0 sizeExistComp, 0 filesTotal, 0     sizeTotal
  Got fatal error during xfer (No files dumped for share /)
  Backup aborted (No files dumped for share /)
  Not saving this as a partial backup since it has fewer files than the prior one (got 0 and 0   files versus 0)

Running /usr/bin/ssh -q -x -n -l root 192.168.1.70 env LC_ALL=C /bin/tar -c -v -f - -C / --totals . at the server commandline (backuppc's sever) I get a connection and see a bunch of tar output on the tty.

The error 65280 seems odd.

There are no further hints in the logs.

Any experts out there care to exchange some wisdom on this one?  Frustrating :)

Answer (score 0):

your tar command has stdout as file output (-f -)
Is this really what you want to do?
I think you would rather backup to a real file or pipe your command

Comment: The -f - is the default for tar backups, so seems right.  I assume backuppc is reading in the tar data through its connection...

Comment: Note also that this same commandline works in backup of the backuppc host itself (localhost) as: $tarPath -c -v -f - -C $shareName+ --totals